# Haste or Prudence: which one is it?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

The help center for [When *shouldn't* I comment?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) states

> **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and [pay it forward](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer);

which means comments like "*thank you @XYZ*" or "*thanks, that's it*" constitute as *noise* and hence, non-constructive.

Two of my flags for comment cleanup have been ***declined with no added explanation***. Both of them were raised for *completely non-constructive* comments:

[image: IMG:] ,
[image: IMG:]

The first comment was posted on my own answer by OP (answer already marked accepted). Regardless, why are they retained on the posts?

I'm not yet aware that Community moderator bot can decline such flags so it is my assumption that a human moderator declined them. Why did they do that is  precisely what I want to know?

I should make it clear that my earlier similar flags were marked helpful and usually, all of the corresponding comments got deleted. The aforesaid ones seems to be exception here. That's why the title reflects: "*haste or prudence*".

---

**Note:** I, at the moment, do not find the need to link the posts behind the comments. Should the links be requested for better comprehensibility of the post, I may consider providing them.

As for the moderators, those are the recent two comments declined against the reason 'not constructive', so you should be able to see them easily in my flag history.

Comment: The history shows that they were indeed declined by a mod, Bryan.  Hopefully he'll weigh in here.  I've cleaned them up.  You might want to flag such comments as "too chatty" instead, since they are not actively anti-constructive (which is how the flag tends to be interpreted).

Comment: Perhaps some background: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169994/should-a-thank-you-comment-be-flagged. Also, my POV (as explained in some answers from there): 1 comment isn't so annoying/offending, especially if it's from new user, I wouldn't flag that. Instead, if there are a lot comments on a single post, that's when I'll flag the *post* with custom flag, requesting for comment clean-up (don't forget to explain the reason!). Anyway, that's my opinion only, and might not apply to other users.

Comment: @AndrewT., per the link it appears that if such a comment comes in the midst of a  discussion or useful comments, then it should be flagged as such (but with "too chatty" reason, as Matthew also suggested here). Otherwise, when they are the only ones on the post, since they do not seem to be offensive, one should not be bothered about them, neither should bother a mod for cleanup, but instead ask the poster not to post them. It reads like a sound advice and is in contrast to my current strict cleanup approach, but I'd like to wait for Bryan's explanation before jumping to the advice here.